# Swift 3: UILabel not showing in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` called `CCLineupTableViewCell` that looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var artistNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var artistValuationLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

I access the cell in the `cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` method like so:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! CCLineupTableViewCell
```

My custom cell setup is like so:

[image]

[image]

As you can see it's setup right in the IB and in the code. The weird thing is that the first label, `artistNameLabel`, is accessible through `cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath` and works perfectly. The `artistValuationLabel`, however, never even shows up despite having default text via the storyboard.

**Edit:**

I've added a picture of the constraints from the nib. It's anchored to the right side, top, and bottom of the cell (as well as the aspect ratio).

[image]

Comment: Did you check `UITableViewCell`constraints, maybe the label is not showing because error constraints.

Comment: @Santiagocarmonagonzález  Constraints are good, but I'll post them.

Comment: try setting to that label a higher value than the `artistNameLabel` in the `Horizontal` property at **content Compression Resistance Priority** Or a constant constraint Width Value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is an error on the constraints you did set.

Add a Width constraint to make sure that `artistValuationLabel` will have space to appear.

Comment: Anyone know why this happens? the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` attribute is set to `true`. Hopefully this will get fixed, as the `aspectRatio` was correctly set (as were all of the other constraints). I had no way of knowing what was wrong if I didn't ask this question.

Comment: It could be happens because the width priority of the `artistNameLabel` is higher than `artistValuationLabel` so when the name is very long that label will take the space "reserved" to the other label. 

When you set a specific Width to `artistValuationLabel` it has a 1000 priority, so this space will be always reserved.

Comment: But the labels do not overlap I've since changed it so that there is a constraint preventing this. I took out the width to see if it would work but it still wouldn't so I had to put it back.

Comment: If you took out  the width constraint and It didn't work is because there are still errors in constraints or maybe the text of the label is empty.

Comment: Text prints to screen via `print(artistValuationLabel.text)`. It's gotta be the constraints - I just don't know where. Either way I'll look out for it, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to improper width constraint this thing is happened. Either You need to add proportional width or you should run in that device for which you have designed.

Comment: You can also give left constraint.